# Check if strings in std::vector contain substring in C++

Tags: c++, string

Is there an efficient way of executing a function if any string inside a vector contains a substring?

Something along these lines

```
if(vector.contains(strstr(currentVectorElement,"substring"))) {
    //do something
}

if(vector.contains(strstr(currentVectorElement,"substring2"))) {
    //do something else
}
```

The only thing I can think of is iterating over each string and check if the substring exists.

Comment: Do you mean efficient in the sense of low number of code lines or low running time?

Comment: @KarstenKoop speed optimized so low running time

Comment: For that it doesn't matter if you loop by hand or use something like `std::find_if` as mentioned below, you still loop over all elements. You would have to use something other than a vector. If you were not looking for substrings, but could compare the whole string, you could use an `unordered_map`, but with substrings it's difficult...

Comment: Efficiency achieved mostly by proper algorithms and data structures. For vector of string the only way is iterating over all elements. If performance of this search is important you should think about different data structure, for example radix tree.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `std::find_if` with a lambda expression

```
if(std::find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](const std::string& str) { return str.find("substring") != std::string::npos; }) != vec.end()) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: `std:any_of` might make more sense here.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is std::search()

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search